# awk scripting to scan files for certain words and create output

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have many lines like:

```
uid: jdoes mail:  jdoes@yahoo.com
mail:  mdoes@yahoo.com uid: mdoes
uid: kdoes mail:  kdoes@yahoo.com
mail:  tdoes@yahoo.com uid: tdoes
```

How do I rearrange them to look like :

```
uid: jdoes mail:  jdoes@yahoo.com
uid: mdoes mail:  mdoes@yahoo.com
uid: kdoes mail:  kdoes@yahoo.com
uid: tdoes mail:  tdoes@yahoo.com
```

Comment: uid: jdoes mail:  jdoes@yahoo.com
mail:  mdoes@yahoo.com uid: mdoes
uid: kdoes mail:  kdoes@yahoo.com
mail:  tdoes@yahoo.com uid: tdoes

How do I rearrange them to look like :

uid: jdoes mail:  jdoes@yahoo.com
uid: mdoes mail:  mdoes@yahoo.com
uid: kdoes mail:  kdoes@yahoo.com
uid: tdoes mail:  tdoes@yahoo.com

Comment: Edit instead of commenting -- comments don't have enough formatting. And I'd use perl here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller - Nah, perl was pretty much born from awk. Think of awk as `perl -p <program>`, although awk is slower in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

The backbone of AWK is to do something for a line that matches something.  You have two types of lines therefore match each and print in a different way for each.  One way to do it is:

```
awk '/^uid/ { print } /^mail/ { print $3" "$4" "$1"  "$2 }' <your files>
```

How does it work:

- For lines starting with `uid` it prints them as they appear;
- for lines starting with `mail` it arranges the columns differently (note the extra space between `$1` and `$2`, since it is in there on the `uid` lines).

(This one is useful if you have other lines in the file.)

---

Another way:

```
awk '/^mail/{$0=$3" "$4" "$1" "$2};1' <your files>
```

How does it work:

- `print` prints `$0` (the full line) by default;
- `;1` is equivalent to `; { print }`;
- we change `$0` for lines matching `^mail`.

(This one is probably faster if you want to process and print *all lines in the file*.  Thanks don_crissti.)

Answer (score 3):

Task can be easy done with **sed**

```
sed 's/^\(mail:\s*\S*\)\s*\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file.lines
```

To be POSIX you should change `\s` to `[[:blank:]]` and `\S` to `[^[:blank:]]` or

```
sed 's/^\(mail:[^:]*\)[[:blank:]]\(.*\)/\2 \1/' file.lines
```